# Где редактировать ссылки с личного кабинета?

Tags: wordpress

Есть виджет с таким кодом:

```
<div class="user_widget_body">
                        <div class="user_widget_body_ins">
                            [list_page]
                            <div class="user_widget_exit">
                                <a href="[exit]" class="exit_link">'. __('Exit','pn') .'</a>
                            </div>                          
                        </div>
                    </div>          
                </div>
            </div>
```

Где мне найти [list_page], чтобы убрать лишние ссылки из личного кабинета? Через виджеты возможность редактировать только заголовок, не больше. В коде только [list_page] нашёл. Куда дальше смотреть?

Comment: Если вы умеете пользоваться инспектором, то можете примерно узнать название секции или блока, а дальше в google ищем что-то типа woocommerce remove action или используйте поиск по файлам

Comment: Через инспектора я нашёл этот блок - user_widget_body , основная проблема в том, что я не могу найти "внутренности list_page", нахожу только             $list_page = pn_list_user_menu();
    
            $array = array(
                '[list_page]' => $list_page,
                '[exit]' => get_ajax_link('logout', 'get'),
                '[title]' => $title_widget,
                '[user_discount]' => get_user_discount($user_id),
            );  . Но функцию pn_list_user_menu нигде больше не могу найти

Comment: А в вашем коде это вообще шорткод, ищите по коду где у вас создаётся этот шорткод и там уже смотрите что и откуда берётся

Comment: Не совсем понял. Пробовал искать pn_list_user_menu - возвращаюсь к тому же коду. list_page - тоже возвращаюсь сюда же. Что я упускаю?

Comment: Тема стандартная? Скрин полей в студию